# Is c function prototype mismatch merely a warning

Tags: c, function, compiler-construction, static

please take a look at my codes below

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printOut()
{
 static int i = 0;
 if (i < 10)
 {
  printOut(i);
 }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  return 0;
}
```

i guess there should be an error due to my invoking the non-existed function prototype.Actually, the code compiles well with mingw5 compiler, which is weird for me, then i change to Borland Compiler, i get a warning message said that no printOut function prototype, is this only a warning ? What is more, the code executes well without any pop-up error windows.

Comment: The only reason it "executes well" is that you never call `printOut`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program's behavior is undefined, because you define `printOut()` with no parameters, but you call it with one argument.  You need to fix it.  But you've written it in such a way that the compiler isn't required to diagnose the problem.  (gcc, for example, doesn't warn about the parameter mismatch, even with `-std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra` -O3.)

The reasons for this are historical.

Pre-ANSI C (prior to 1989) didn't have prototypes; function declarations could not specify the expected type or number of arguments.  Function *definition*, on the other hand, specified the function's parameters, but not in a way that the compiler could use to diagnose mismatched calls.  For example, a function with one int parameter might be declared (say, in a header file) like this:

```
int plus_one();
```

and defined (say, in the corresponding .c file) like this:

```
int plus_one(n)
int n;
{
     return n + 1;
}
```

The parameter information was buried inside the definition.

ANSI C added prototypes, so the above could written like this:

```
int plus_one(int n);

int plus_one(int n)
{
    return n + 1;
}
```

But the language continued to support the old-style declarations and definitions, so as not to break existing code.  Even the upcoming C201X standard still permits pre-ANSI function declarations and definitions, though they've been obsolescent for 22 years now.

In your definition:

```
void printOut()
{
    ...
}
```

you're using an old-style function definition.  It says that printOut has no parameters -- but it doesn't let the compiler warn you if you call it incorrectly.  Inside your function you call it with one argument.  The behavior of this call is *undefined*.  It could quietly ignore the extraneous argument -- or it could conceivably corrupt the stack and cause your program to die horribly.  (The latter is unlikely; for historical reasons, most C calling conventions are tolerant of such errors.)

If you want your printOut() function to have no parameters *and* you want the compiler to complain if you call it incorrectly, define it as:

```
void printOut(void)
{
    ...
}
```

This is the one and only correct way to write it in C.

Of course if you simply make this change in your program and then add a call to `printOut()` in `main()`, you'll have an infinite recursive loop on your hands.  You probably want `printOUt()` to take an `int` argument:

```
void printOut(int n)
{
    ...
}
```

---

As it happens, C++ has different rules.  C++ was derived from C, but with less concern for backward compatibility.  When Stroustrup added prototypes to C++, he dropped old-style declarations altogether.  Since there was no need for a special-case `void` marker for parameterless functions, `void printOut()` *in C++* says explicitly that `printOut` has no parameters, and a call with arguments is an error.  C++ also permits `void printOut(void)` for compatibility with C, but that's probably not used very often (it's rarely useful to write code that's both valid C and valid C++.)  C and C++ are two different languages; you should follow the rules for whichever language you're using.

Comment: Actually the program's behavior is well-defined because the function that would invoke UB is never called from `main`.

Answer (score 6):

In C, a function without any parameters can still take parameters.

That's why it compiles. The way to specify that it doesn't take any parameters is:

```
void printOut(void)
```

This is the proper way to do, but is less common especially for those from a C++ background.

Comment: I don't think "most people" do that. Maybe if "most people" are a bit too used to C++ they do. ;)

Comment: -1 for "outdated". using `void` as argument list is the proper way to declare/define a function that takes no arguments. Using empty parenthesis is just plain bad as it doesn't provide a prototype. Without a prototype the compiler cannot catch your mistakes for you.

Comment: It's not actually that simple. A function can take a variable number of parameters only if it is **defined** with `...` as last argument.

Comment: I disagree that the *correct* `(void)` form is "less common" in any sense.  C++ programmers who write `void printOut()` rather than `void printOut(void)` *when writing in C* are simply doing it wrong.  C and C++ have different rules, because they're different languages.  And a C function declared with `()` does *not* take a variable number of arguments; it takes the exact number and type(s) of arguments specified in the definition.  The missing information in the declaration just prevents the compiler for diagnosing incorrect calls.  *Always* use prototypes.

Comment: @Keith: I agree mostly with what you say, but what I was referring to about the "less common" part is that those with C++ backgrounds, tend to both declare and define their functions with `void printOut()`. (Omitting the `void`.)

Comment: That may well be true (I hope it isn't) -- but it just means that they're doing it wrong, writing incorrect C code because of assumptions they've brought over from C++.  (I learned C first, so I don't really know how common this is.)

Comment: @Keith: I came from a C++/Java background myself. So I was one of those people who used to do this. Considering how they teach mainly C++/Java in school now, this is common enough.