# function prototype mismatch, still program runs on Visual studio 2008 and gcc compiler

Tags: c

Function prototype is different than call and definition; still it does not give any error on Visual studio and gcc compiler

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    void print(); //prototype

    void main()
    {
          print(2,2); //calling
    }

    void print(int a,int b) //definition
    {
        printf("\na=%d\tb=%d",a,b);
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is c function prototype mismatch merely a warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540341/is-c-function-prototype-mismatch-merely-a-warning)

Comment: Your compiler is just being nice to you. Or evil. Possibly both.

Comment: `void print()`is not a prototype. And `void main()` should be `int main(void)`

Answer (score 1):

With the above declared function prototype, 
**you can pass any number of arguments to the function irrespective of the number of arguments it takes**.

Like for example

```
#include<stdio.h>

void print();//prototype

void main()
{
      print(2,2);//calling
      print(3);           // This would also work output a = 3, b = garbage value
      print(4,5,6);       // This would also work output a = 4, b = 5
}

void print(int a,int b)//defination
{
    printf("\na=%d\tb=%d",a,b);
}
```

Note : If you don't want to pass any arguments to a function, it is advisable to use void
like **void print(void);**

Comment: void print(int *);
void main()
{
 int *ptr1=0,*ptr2=0;
 print(ptr1,ptr2);
}
void print(int *a,int *b)
{
 printf("\na=%d\tb=%d",a,b);
}
this also works

Comment: In case of gcc it would through an error, but in case of Visual studio the compiler being smart enough will through this warning  warning " C4020: 'print' : too many actual parameters" and still continue to run. Which means it is compiler dependent

Answer (score 0):

**6.7.5.3 Function declarators (including prototypes) 14**

> An identifier list declares only the identifiers of the parameters of
>   the function. An empty list in a function declarator that is part of a
>   definition of that function specifies that the function has no
>   parameters. The empty list in a function declarator that is not part
>   of a definition of that function specifies that no information about
>   the number or types of the parameters is supplied.

`void print();//prototype` will be considered a prototype such as having a no specified argument.

Comment: note : It will be considered as there is no argument in `C++`.